# How do I set up my AWS EC2 Elastic Beanstalk project to collaborate with others?

Tags: version-control, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been working on AWS EC2 using Elastic Beanstalk for a few months now. Everything is going well. Now, the client wants to add another developer to the project. I am a little unclear as to how to do this. It seems that Elastic Beanstalk is using git in the background and is push only. I can't clone the repo. I am not even sure where to go to *find* the repo.

So, my question is, how to I set things up (or have others set things up) so they can collaborate with me?

**EDIT: I suppose another way of asking this question is: If Elastic Beanstalk has set up my Git repo for me, how to I check that Repo out and share it with others?**

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (with AWS tools installed) on a Windows 7 machine and the remote instance is Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk doesn't have any concept of a repo.  An application version is just bundle that's stored on S3.

What you'll have to do is host a repo at someplace like Github or Bitbucket.  Then you share your changes as you would any other project.  When it comes time to deploy a version to Elastic Beanstalk, you'd execute `git aws.push` rather than something like `git push origin`.  Of course this assumes that you've already [set up the AWS git dev tools](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.sdlc.html).

As an aside, I'd recommend that you set up an IAM user account for each developer so everyone has their own set of AWS access keys.  This would allow you to revoke deployment access to a person without affecting anyone else.

Comment: thanks jamie. yes, i have set up IAM previously. I suspected that I'd have to set up Git, but hoped that there was some version control under the hood. Anyway, thanks again...

Comment: I have the code now for an existing project from github, but how can I set configuration so I can push to this specific app ?, any help with that ?